# How to use and echo array_pop for multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to randomize a multi-dimensional array, echo out both values and then remove it from the array.

With a one dimensional array I would just use the `array_pop()` function. But since it's not, I'm kind of lost.

I have made some code how I would do it as if it was a 1 dimensional array.

**PHP**

```
$id = array(
    array(4534534, "JohnDoe"),
    array(2432423, "Foobar"),
);

$random = $id;    // make a copy of the array
shuffle($random); // randomize the order

//I think this part needs to be modified
//should echo out $random[0][0] and $random[0][1] for example
//then remove from the array
echo array_pop($random);
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly? If `$arr = array("foo", "bar")` do you know how to print out the two values?

Comment: That's the issue. array_pop only returns 1 value if I'm not mistaking. And since it's a multi-dimensional array I don't know how I can echo out both values of the last array in the array when I'm using the array_pop method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is completely correct. Your only mistake is, that you can not echo out an an array, you'll have to do that manually like this:

```
$result = array_pop($random);
echo $result[0] . $result[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the popped value in a variable, and then use a quick foreach to echo them out.

```
$random = $id;    // make a copy of the array
shuffle($random); // randomize the order

$samples = array_pop($random);
foreach ($samples as $sample){
    echo $sample;   
}
```